# Bootrap offset xs and visible xs not working as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a web site using Bootstrap 3 to design it. I have come across a situation where the the grid system is not working as expected.

[image]

I am trying to fit in the HTML5 logo in the last line where I have set the class to `visible-xs-6` `col-xs-offset-3`. According to me, this should create three sections where the first section should be an offset of 3 columns which is showing up fine as you can see in the image, but after that I believe that the HTML5 logo should be somewhere in the middle section and another 3 column section after that. Isn't that logical? But for some reason the second section is taking up the whole row after the offset. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: A screenshot of your code is not really going to help us debug it. Please post some actual code, preferably so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I just realised that the screenshot is not very helpful on the PC. On the Android device it was opening up just fine. I found the solution to my problem. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the `visible-xs-*` classes are used to set the number of columns, only the `display:*` property. The only options are `block`, `inline` and `inline-block`. So your classes should be...

```
class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 visible-xs-block"
```

Comment: [Check this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) I think they can be used for column widths. Check this out.

Comment: @Rohan Yeah exactly... did you actually read it? They are only for `display:` properties, and not column widths.

Comment: Oh I get it now, the * is for the options given below that. I presumed the * was for number of columns. Thank you so much. It makes so much sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake. I forgot to wrap the columns in a `<div class="row">`. And moreover I used .hidden-sm .hidden-md and .hidden-lg classes just to be extra sure.

And plus I made another silly mistake of assuming that the * in `visible-xs-*` means the number of columns instead of the options given in responsive utilities.

If anyone has a similar problem please take a look at [Bootstrap's responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Anyway thank you anyone who tried to help. I will accept this as an answer to close the question.